# Converting Blob from SQLite Helper to X509 Certificate

Tags: c#, powershell

We have a blob string from a SQLite Helper android database, the thing is that we know this value is a X509 certificate, so, how can we get the bytes of this blob string and import them creating a X509 certificate using either powershell or C#?

Greetings

Comment: Have you made any attempts to implement this using C# or powershell?

Comment: Start by looking at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148413(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148417(v=vs.110).aspx. you will need to determine, however, how the string is encoded so you can convert it back to a byte[].

Comment: We know the string is ciphered with AES-CBC 256 and encoded in ASN.1